# Simple MySQL Query to return one customer name out of a customer table

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling to work out a MySQL query. I've tried making a query which I have posted below but it never returns the correct value. For example I'm searching in the customer table for "John Smith" it will return other entries but never John Smith.

This is the query:

```
SELECT customerName
  FROM Customer 
 WHERE customerName < 'John Smith';
```

Comment: typo on your where clause? assume you want `customerName = 'John Smith'`

Answer (score 1):

Try 
    `SELECT customerName FROM Customer WHERE customerName = 'John Smith';`

Or maybe 
    `SELECT customerName FROM Customer WHERE customerName LIKE '%John%Smith%';`

Btw. in your query you are searching for any customerName that is smaller than John Smith. Most Databases will give all alphabetically lower Names i suppose. If you allways just want one name think about adding `LIMIT 1` to your query.

Comment: I was going to suggest the LIKE method. If that still doesn't work, double check the data type in your table. I spent 10 minutes trying to figure out why WHERE x = 1 wasn't working, and it turns out that "x" had been set as a varchar instead of an int.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT customerName FROM Customer WHERE customerName LIKE '%John%Smith%';
```

I'd recommend you check the MySQL forum and learn some basic SQL syntax.